# Add a pytest option that doesn't have dashes?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a lot of tests that take a long time to run. Luckily, the time these tests take is evenly distributed among tests for several subsystems of my project.

I'm using IPython's pytest magic commands. I'd like to be able to just say things like

```
pytest potato_peeler --donttesti18n --runstresstests
```

or

```
pytest garlic_squeezer --donttestsmell --logperfdata
```

but I can't add the `garlic_squeezer` and `potato_peeler` options the same way I do `logperfdata` et al because **`parser.addoption` gets upset if the option name doesn't start with a `--`.**

I know this seems like a tiny inconvenience, but I have a ton of people running these tests several times a day and I'd like the way they're invoked to make as much sense as possible, by emulating how you issue commands on a command line (command, thing you want to run the command on, then --flags.)

**Is there a way have non-dashed options**? (that doesn't involve writing a full-blown pytest plugin that overrides the option parsing?)

I was hoping to use the `pytest_commandline_parse` hook but [you can't use that hook in a `conftest.py`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_cmdline_parse), you have to write a full-blown plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark your tests and run only those with some mark.

For example:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.runstresstests
def test_stress_something():
    pass

@pytest.mark.logperfdata
def test_something_quick():
    pass

...
```

If you only want to run stress tests: `pytest -m runstresstests`

Full documentation at https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html

Comment: Then I have to do the -m thing, though! The hope was to not have to put a dash in front of it at all...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know. What is the problem with the dash? I was thinking just something "that doesn't involve writing a full-blown pytest plugin that overrides the option parsing". It is something already implemented by pytest.

Comment: The dash is just a little bit of unecessary friction is all. It's like how ipython gives you the option to call functions without putting parentheses after them; having to type that one extra character that doesn't actually mean anything adds up to a significant amount of frustration (and miskeying) if it's on something you have to do all the time. Thanks for trying anyway. :P